# Nodejs ORM for Postgers spatial indexes (like PostGIS)

Tags: node.js, postgis, sequelize.js, node-orm2

Postgres is the DB of choice due to its spatial indexing goodness (top-k-closest-points) using PostGIS or other gists. Looks like Node.js ORMs do not directly support spatial indexing, so which one requires the least amount of hacking for this? Sequelize and node-orm-2 seem to demand some hacking to get it working. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of [sequelize 3.4.0](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/master/changelog.md#340), Geometry support has been added for postgres.  You can use the GEOMETRY datatype in the model definition:

```
sequelize.define("point", {
  geom: DataTypes.GEOMETRY
});
```

Comment: But no support for box or extent https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/other-data-types/#miscellaneous-datatypes